SharePoint 2013 publicly hosted website with InfoPath Forms replacement
I am looking for a solution to replace a SharePoint 2013 publicly hosted website that includes InfoPath forms. Microsoft's documentation suggests Go Daddy and Wix, and I have also found a recommendation for Power Pages, but it is not clear whether any of these options would offer a content management solution with forms similar to SharePoint 2013/InfoPath. Note that the forms are very detailed. Data is collected in the forms and copied to an on-premises SharePoint 2016 environment.
Can anyone recommend a CMS public website hosting solution that includes a forms solution comparable to InfoPath?
